# Where can I find a google search results re-linker for Google Chrome that works?

Tags: google-chrome, images, javascript, google-search, greasemonkey

There used to be some grease monkey scripts that helped relink results directly from the Google search (see [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/53226) and [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/reviews/24102) for regular results, and  [here](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/5059) and [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecfjhfglbnbhmpehpjfdoklmkbnbknjg) for image results.)

I really enjoyed using those scripts because it I didn't need to send one more HTTP request via google, and I could also right click and copy the URL without getting a big redirect string (try it if you're wondering what I'm talking about - see image below)

So my question is where can I find a script that is:

1. Currently working
2. Can be installed on Google Chrome (ps: this is not hard - google chrome can install most greasemonkey scripts and userscipts without any modifications)
3. It needs to also work with google's secure search (httpS instead of http://google.com)
4. BONUS: If the script works on google image search or if you have a separate one that would also be REALLY great.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Firefox use the two links posted by TreyK. For Google Chrome use [A Little Privacy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kjhmfidomefgpbbebodnbakelpabilga)

> Prevents passing referrer to third parties, removes redirect trackers, resolves short URLs, and more.
>
> This extension attempts to prevent passing referrer data through links to third parties by adding noreferrer to the rel attribute. It detects page changes, so that links will still get processed for pages like Google's Instant Search or infinitely scrolling pages like Twitter and Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked quite well for me for fixing links in the regular Google search: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/95092

- The author seems to have kept it current over this past year (last update was November 2nd)
- I was only able to test with Firefox/Greasemonkey, but it should work fine with Chrome
- It actually does work with HTTPS

This script will fix the image links for you: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/118947

- Also well-maintained (last update was November 24th)
- Also works with HTTPS
- Also tested with Firefox/Greasemonkey

Install both of them and using Google should become much less annoying!

Comment: They look great but i'm not having any luck with them on chrome yet. maybe i will use FF to verify they are working there?

Comment: nice - working well on FF. i just need to see if i can make it run on chrome now

Comment: That's odd, I didn't know that there could be major incompatibilities between Firefox and Chrome. Sorry it's not working for you.

Comment: It's not a bad start. I'm trying to see if I can debug it. Thanks for your post.